# whether I need a google app engine for my android app

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am working on an Android App which requires users to perform these tasks:

1. user sign-up using Facebook API
2. send data to server to store data
3. perform a ajax query
4. perform a search query

So my question is whether I need a GAE mobile Back end for my App or else which is most suitable.

Comment: Is it a dumb question or is my concept wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, you won't need Google App Engine for this.
2. Depends. App Engine does not store data itself, it is a Platform-as-a-Service. To save data you can use a variety of storage methods. For your case the following might be interesting:

   - Google Cloud Datastore, a schemaless non-relational way of storing data.
   - Google Cloud SQL, a MySQL database in the cloud.
   - Google Cloud Storage, a NoSQL way of storing data.
3. Perform an ajax query is a somewhat vague task. If you mean retrieving data using Ajax, then you need to know that Google App Engine does not use Ajax at all. In fact, it saves you the trouble by introducing endpoints. [Click here for more info](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/).
4. Search query is not very specific either. If you want to search, you could do that with the [Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries) API, Cloud SQL or Cloud Storage API. You might also be interested in the [Search API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/) for more complex searches through big amounts of data.

I hope you'll be able to figure out what suits you best. I advise reading through the documentation thoroughly and explore all API's and methods for storage.

If you'd like to experiment with Datastore (which I personally think would suit your case), take a look at [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial).

Comment: No problem. If my answer was useful, please accept it by clicking on the icon at the left.